# GIT - extra changes that should not be in branch diff

Tags: git

I have a problem with extra changes that appears on my branch. This is a scenario:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout -b my-new-branch
git diff master..my-new-branch
```

And I can see there are lot of changes provided already. 
These changes comes from different branches. Why?

I'm almost sure that if I provide some changes on this branch, commit and push the changes it will also include the changes from `git diff`.

Comment: Which branch were you on before Step 1?

Comment: @ElpieKay probably different one (let's say my-old-branch). What exacly do you want to know?

Comment: If `my-old-branch` is not `master`, `git diff master..my-new-branch` can show many changes you do not expect. If you wanted to create `my-new-branch` from the newest `master`, you could run `git checkout master;git pull origin --rebase master;git checkout -b my-new-branch;`. Now your `master` may have been polluted by other branches. I'm not sure how to make things right because I don't know your real situation.